# What type of math is this: a -> b -> c

Tags: math, haskell, types, monads

I often see type declarations similar to this when looking at Haskell:

```
a -> (b -> c)
```

I understand that it describes a function that takes in something of type a and returns a new function that takes in something of type b and returns something of type c. I also understand that types are associative (edit: I was wrong about this - see the comments below), so the above could be rewritten like this to get the same result:

```
(a -> b) -> c
```

This would describe a function that takes in something of type a and something of type b and returns something of type c.

I've also heard that you can make a complement (edit: really, the word I was looking for here is dual - see the comments below) to the function by switching the arrows:

```
a <- b <- c
```

which I think is equivalent to

```
c -> b -> a
```

but I'm not sure.

My question is, what is the name of this kind of math? I'd like to learn more about it so I can use it to help me write better programs. I'm interested in learning things like what a complimentary function is, and what other transformations can be performed on type declarations.

Thanks!

Comment: `a -> b -> c` and `a -> (b -> c)` take an `a` and return a (function that takes a `b` and returns a `c`), i.e. they take two arguments. `(a -> b) -> c` takes a (function that takes an `a` and returns a `b`) and returns a `c`, i.e. they take one argument. So they're not equivalent!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Speaking broadly this falls into the realm of [Lambda Calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus).

Since this notation has to do with types of functions [type inference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference) might be of interest to you as well.

(The wrong assumptions you made about associativity should already be cleared up sufficiently by the other answers so i will not reiterate that)

Comment: Also, the notion of duals to functions comes from [category theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory), which is something that can be fun, interesting, and enlightening to functional programmers.

Comment: Dualism, right, that was the word I was looking for. I remembered it wrong from the video I watched about it. Thanks!

Comment: In particular, this is "typed lambda calculus."  In regular lambda calculus, there is only one "type."  And yes, it is related to Category Theory, and, in particular, Topos theory. (That's because in Category theory, objects and functions are seperate ideas, but in Topos theory, there is an "internal" notion of a function.

Comment: One can just specify and say that we're working with categories which are cartesian closed.

Answer (score 10):

Type declarations are **not** associative, `a -> (b -> c)` is not equivalent to `(a -> b) -> c`. Also, you can't "switch" the arrows, `a <- b <- c` is not valid syntax.

The usual reference to associativity is in this case that `->` it [*right associative*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity), which means that `a -> b -> c` is interpreted as `a -> (b -> c)`.

Answer (score 4):

```
a -> (b -> c)
```

and

```
(a -> b) -> c
```

are *not* equivalent in Haskell. That is type theory which can be founded in category theory.

The former is a function taking an argument of type `a` and returning a function of type `b -> c`. While the latter is a function taking a function of type `a -> b` as argument and returning a value of type `c`.

What do you mean by the complement of a function? The type of the inverse function of a function of type `a -> (b -> c)` has the type `(b -> c) -> a`.

Comment: It looks like the word I was looking for was the 'dual' of a function. I made a note in the question above so no one else gets confused.

Answer (score 2):

Functions of type `a->b->c`, which are actually chains of functions like you said, are examples of [Currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)